# Prove that the Pontryagin dual of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: harmonic-analysis, duality-theorems

From Wikipedia: the group of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, is isomorphic to its own dual; the characters on $\mathbb{R}$ are of the form $r \to e^{i\theta r}$.

How can I prove this assertion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This assertion is shown in the appendix on page $10$ of K. Conrad's notes about the [character group of $\mathbb{Q}$](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/characterQ.pdf). His proof for $\mathbb{R}$ is elementary, not using integrals (which is done in Conway's book on functional analysis). For more references see also [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48170/what-is-the-pontryagin-dual-of-the-rationals).