# If $G=\mathbb {R}$, how $\hat{f}(\chi)=\int_{G}f(x)\overline{\chi (x)}dx$ becomes $\hat{f}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)e^{-ix\xi}dx$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

The dual group of a locally compact Abelian group is used as the underlying space for an abstract version of the Fourier transform. If a function $f$ is in $L^{1}(G)$, then the Fourier transform is the function $\hat{f}$ on $\hat{G}$ defined by

$\hat{f}(\chi)=\int_{G}f(x)\overline{\chi (x)}dx$

---

if $G=\mathbb{R}$, then how can I prove that the Fourier transform is of the form below?

$\hat{f}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)e^{-ix\xi}dx$

Comment: If $G = \mathbb{R}$, then $\hat{G} = \{\chi_{\xi} \colon x \mapsto e^{ix\xi} \mid \xi \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: You can't *prove* a definition. Also, when you work with the group $\mathbf R$ you have to make a *convention* about how you think of $\widehat{\mathbf R}$ as $\mathbf R$ in order to let the Fourier transform be regarded as a function on $\mathbf R$ instead of on the abstract $\widehat{\mathbf R}$. Frankly I'd use the factor $e^{2\pi ix\xi}$ in my definition of the Fourier transform. There are many possible conventions, so a "proof" is impossible.

Comment: Maybe you are asking for a proof that $\widehat{\mathbf R}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf R$ as topological groups?  If so, make that clearer.

Comment: You asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671453/prove-that-the-pontryagin-duality-of-mathbbr-is-mathbbr) for a proof that the dual of $\Bbb R$ is $\Bbb R$…

Comment: thanks Daniel. if we have $\hat{G}=\left \{ \chi_{\xi}:x \mapsto e^{ix\xi}\mid \xi\in\mathbb{R} \right \}$, how can we complete the proof?

Comment: Yes Watson. I know that $\hat{G}=\left \{ \chi_{\xi}:x \mapsto e^{ix\xi}\mid \xi\in\mathbb{R} \right \}$. but nevertheless i can not complete the proof of this assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was said in the comments, 
$$\Psi : G=\Bbb R \to \hat{G} = \{\chi_{\xi} \,\colon x \mapsto e^{ix\xi} \mid \xi \in \mathbb{R}\}, \xi \mapsto \chi_{_{\xi}}$$
is a group isomorphism.

Then define
$$\hat f(\xi) := \hat f(\Psi(\xi)) = \hat f(\chi_{\xi}) = \int_{G}f(x)\overline{\chi_{\xi} (x)} dx$$

We get
$$\hat f(\xi) = \int_{G}f(x)\overline{\chi_{\xi} (x)}dx =
\int_{G}f(x)\overline{e^{ix\xi}}dx =
\int_{G}f(x)e^{-ix\xi}dx$$

as desired.