# Unitary dual of $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb R$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, harmonic-analysis

How to prove that, the unitary dual of $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb R$ are the trivial identity representation $id$ and the representation $\chi_x (y) = e^{i x y}; y\in \mathbb R$,  respectively.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a finite group $G$, the number of inequivalent irreducible unitary 
representations equals the number of conjugacy classes of $G$. The trivial group only has one conjugacy class.
The second question on $\mathbb{R}$ has been answered at [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671453/prove-that-the-pontryagin-duality-of-mathbbr-is-mathbbr).