Can we define a limit of group actions?
Let $\{S_n\}$ be a series of group actions, where $S_n=\operatorname{Sym}(\{1,2,\dots,n\})$ for all $n$.
So the sequence is the following: $\operatorname{Sym}(\{1\})$, $\operatorname{Sym}(\{1,2\})$, $\dots$.
Then, if there exists a concept such as 'limit of a group action', then I think the limit of this sequence $S_n$, should be $\operatorname{Sym}(\Bbb N)$.
What is interesting is that some sequence of well defined finite group may not have its limit. For example, limit of $Z_n=\langle(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ \cdots\ n)\rangle$ will not become a group. Its generator $z = (1\ 2\ \cdots\ n)$ will be a action that sends $1\mapsto2$, $2\mapsto3$, and so on which will not have a element $x$ that $x\mapsto1$ ($1$ is not in the image of action $z$) when $n$ becomes infinite, so inverse of $z$ is not defined. Every element of a group must have its inverse, so limit of $Z_n$ is not a group.
Though it seems obvious, I'm having a hard time defining this kind of logic clearly. I've searched about limits of various entities, but couldn't find that matches this exactly. The most related concept was 'limits of groups'. Nevertheless, limit of groups were defined as sequence of homomorphisms: which makes the group smaller and smaller and eventually converge into smaller finite group. However, what I want is a concept of the group action getting bigger and bigger, eventually converging into infinite group.

A direct or inverse limit might be what you’re trying to define, but it’s not clear how your limit is defined.

I wouldn't expect the limit (whatever that means here!) to be $\text{Sym}(\mathbb{N})$, I'd expect it to be the subgroup of $\text{Sym}(\mathbb{N})$ consisting of elements which only move finitely letters.

The colimit of $S_0 \to S_1 \to S_2 \to \dots$ is the group of finitely supported permutations of $\mathbb{N}$, see here.

regarding your second example, in order to make it in any way a well behaved limit you would have to include as a group $Z_n \hookrightarrow Z_{m}$. In particular this is only possible if $m$ is a multiple of $n$. If you keep that stable (lets say $n,n^2,n^3...$), what you are constructing will be the group of $n$-adic numbers: $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Discussed here (without the group actions but those aren't hard to include): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4528531/can-we-define-a-limit-of-a-sequence-of-groups/4528933#4528933
